# How can I signal cancellation to Web API actions when the self-hosted OWIN server shuts down?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I have an OWIN-based ASP.NET Web API hosted in a Windows Service. Most of my `ApiController` actions are async, and accept `CancellationToken` parameters:

```
[Route("data/{id}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetSomeDataAsync(int id, CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        using (var _dataSource = ...)
        {
            return Ok(await _dataSource.GetDataAsync(id, token));
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
}
```

Using the built-in request-cancellation features of Web API, if the client cancels the request, `token` is signaled and `_dataSource` handles it appropriately and throws the `OperationCanceledException`.

So far, so great.

But when my host process *terminates* (that is, the Windows Service stops), `token` isn't signaled and the cancellation-and-bail-out process isn't graceful.

I'm aware of the OWIN environment dictionary's **host.onAppDisposing** property, and I've dug into the source for the **Microsoft.Owin[.*]** and **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.*** packages to try and figure out where `GetSomeDataAsync`'s `token` argument is coming from, but I'm not sure how to connect the pieces together.

I'd like to do something like

```
class WebServiceInAWindowsService : ServiceBase
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    ...
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure how to get `_cts` to be the source of the `CancellationTokens` that get fed to my actions, *while not breaking* the request-cancellation feature that's working well.

I'm thinking that `CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource()` might be useful, but I'm not seeing how to put the pieces together.

Can you help? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`host.onAppDisposing` is triggered when you call `Dispose` on the value returned from `WebApp.Start`.

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/9f6e09af6bf203744feb5347121fe25f6eec06d8/src/Microsoft.Owin.Hosting/Engine/HostingEngine.cs#L302-L308

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/9f6e09af6bf203744feb5347121fe25f6eec06d8/src/Microsoft.Owin.Hosting/Engine/HostingEngine.cs#L112

`GetSomeDataAsync`'s is only associated with the request disconnect token by default (e.g. `owin.CallCancelled`). Via middleware or otherwise you can replace it with a linked TCS that's also connected to `host.onAppDisposing`.

Something like:

```
app.Use(async (env, next) =>
{
  var reqAbt = env.Get<CancellationToken>("owin.CallCancelled");
  var appAbt = env.Get<CancellationToken>("host.onAppDisposing"); 
  using (linked = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(reqAbt, appAbt))
  {
    env["owin.CallCancelled"] = linked.Token;
    await next();
    env["owin.CallCancelled"] = reqAbt;
  }
});
```